# нужно ли высшее образование, курсы, и другие формальные подтверждения профессионализма?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Тяготею к самообучению при помощи различных книг и интерактива. Мне 20 лет, образование средне-специальное юридическое; начинаю, как и многие, с языка python, хотел бы стать back end разработчиком. Собственно, вопрос - смогу ли я вообще дойти до стадии собеседования, где смог бы показать свои компетенции , если эйчар не увидит у меня сертификатов с курсов, высшего образования или хотя бы образования c технической направленностью? Стоит ли получать такое формальное подтверждение чтобы войти в it? Всем спасибо

Comment: ну для начала, нужно умение искать ответ на простейшие вопросы на ютубе

Comment: Часто никто у вас не будет спрашивать профильного образования, хотя в некоторых конторах близких к ГОС сектору это может стать преградой(например Сбербанк). Однако, если есть возможность и время, я все равно рекомендовал бы вам пройти обучение в каком нибудь вузе с ИТ направленностью, так как Вам  там дадут очень полезную базу по алгоритмам и отличные навыки по самообучению(в перспективе это довольно полезные вещи). А так же вы сможете изучить и попробовать очень много интересных вещей, что в последствии позволит вам не только подзаработать но и получать истинное удовольствие от работы

Comment: Если не отправить никуда резюме, то не узнаете сможете ли дойти до стадии собеседования или нет. Если компания небольшая, то HR "отдел" может состоять из одного кадровика, а резюме просматривать будет техлид. Тогда уже все будет зависеть от того, какие навыки вы указали в резюме. По поводу знания Python - для работы знать только язык недостаточно, нужно знать стек технологий (ту же Django, например, и базы данных, если собираетесь работать backend разработчиком)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> смогу ли я вообще дойти до стадии собеседования, где смог бы показать
>   свои компетенции , если эйчар не увидит у меня сертификатов с курсов,
>   высшего образования или хотя бы образования c технической
>   направленностью? Стоит ли получать такое формальное подтверждение
>   чтобы войти в it?

Сможете. Для работодателя главное, что Вы умеете делать. Да и не в каждой конторе хватают звёзды с неба.

Другое дело, что с профильным образованием шансы получить хорошую работу намного выше. Да и работать будет проще. Всё-таки образование даёт системные знания, плюс многое из того, что Вам в процессе учёбы будут говорить не доступно для тех, кто полностью полагается на самообучение. Просто в большинстве книг и тем более видеокурсов нет даже отсылок к этим вещам, хотя это фундаментальные вещи без которых делать серьёзные проекты ой как тяжело.

Также не стоит забывать, что в процессе обучения (обычно в ВУЗе или колледже) может быть организована практика, на которой можно получить пусть начальный, но всё же навык участия в реальном проекте.

Кроме того корочка как бы там ни было говорит о том, что Вы в профессии уже не случайный человек. Без неё в глазах HR Вы будете просто очередным человеком с улицы. Со всеми вытекающими отсюда последствиями.

Да Вы и сами рано или поздно почувствуете, что при прочих равных, Вам не будет хватать самых обычных "институтских" знаний.